# Trouble displaying C# stack trace in WinDbg

Tags: c#, windbg, stack-trace, handle-leak

I have a handle leak in a C# program. I'm trying to diagnose it using WinDbg using !htrace, roughly as presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617994/1496914), but when I run !htrace -diff in WinDbg I'm presented with stack traces that don't show the names of my C# functions (or even my .net assembly).

I created a small test program to illustrate my difficulty. This program does nothing except "leak" handles.

```
class Program
{
    static List<Semaphore> handles = new List<Semaphore>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Fun1();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    static void Fun1()
    {
        handles.Add(new Semaphore(0, 10));            
    }
}
```

I compiled the assembly, and then in WinDbg I go "File" -> "Open Executable" and select my program (D:\Projects\Sandpit\bin\Debug\Sandpit.exe). I continue program execution, break it, and run "!htrace -enable", then continue for a bit longer, and then break and run "!htrace -diff". This is what I get:

```
0:004> !htrace -enable
Handle tracing enabled.
Handle tracing information snapshot successfully taken.
0:004> g
(1bd4.1c80): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=7ffda000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=77b2f17d esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=77ac410c esp=0403fc20 ebp=0403fc4c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
77ac410c cc              int     3
0:004> !htrace -diff
Handle tracing information snapshot successfully taken.
0xd new stack traces since the previous snapshot.
Ignoring handles that were already closed...
Outstanding handles opened since the previous snapshot:
--------------------------------------
Handle = 0x00000250 - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x00001b58, Process ID = 0x00001bd4

0x77ad5704: ntdll!ZwCreateSemaphore+0x0000000c
0x75dcdcf9: KERNELBASE!CreateSemaphoreExW+0x0000005e
0x75f5e359: KERNEL32!CreateSemaphoreW+0x0000001d
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\13c079cdc1f4f4cb2f8f1b66c8642faa\System.ni.dll
0x65d7e805: System_ni+0x0020e805
0x65d47843: System_ni+0x001d7843
0x65d477ef: System_ni+0x001d77ef
0x004700c9: +0x004700c9
0x67d73dd2: clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x00000034
0x67d9cf6d: clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x0000006b
0x67d9d267: clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x00000152
0x67eb10e0: clr!RunMain+0x000001aa
0x67eb1200: clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0x00000124
--------------------------------------
Handle = 0x0000024c - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x00001b58, Process ID = 0x00001bd4

0x77ad5704: ntdll!ZwCreateSemaphore+0x0000000c
0x75dcdcf9: KERNELBASE!CreateSemaphoreExW+0x0000005e
0x75f5e359: KERNEL32!CreateSemaphoreW+0x0000001d
0x65d7e805: System_ni+0x0020e805
0x65d47843: System_ni+0x001d7843
0x65d477ef: System_ni+0x001d77ef
0x004700c9: +0x004700c9
0x67d73dd2: clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x00000034
0x67d9cf6d: clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x0000006b
0x67d9d267: clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x00000152
0x67eb10e0: clr!RunMain+0x000001aa
0x67eb1200: clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0x00000124
...
--------------------------------------
Displayed 0xd stack traces for outstanding handles opened since the previous snapshot.
```

As you can see, the stack trace is missing my C# function names "Main" and "Fun1". I believe "System_ni+0x..." frames may be my function frames, but I don't know. My question is, how do I get WinDbg to display function names for my C# functions in the stack trace?

Extra information:
My WinDbg symbol search path is

> SRV*C:/symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;D:\Projects\Sandpit\bin\Debug;srv*

I don't get any errors when I open the executable in WinDbg. There is a file called "Sandpit.pdb" in the output directory ("D:\Projects\Sandpit\bin\Debug"). The project is built locally so the pdb file should match the exe. I downloaded WinDbg [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx). I have "Enable native code debugging" checked in the project settings in Visual Studio.

Comment: Looking at stack traces isn't going to tell you that the list is storing handles.  You need to look at the heap instead.  Pretty painful in Windbg, the heap is a huge fire hose.  Do consider a .NET memory profiler instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WinDbg attempts to interpret the native call stack as best it can, however to fully interpret the stack of a CLR application WinDbg needs to use an extension called [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx).  This extension has a separate command `CLRStack` for viewing the stack information of CLR stacks.  You will need to load the SOS extension first however using the `.loadby sos clr` command (or similar, I remember getting the correct version SOS to load could be a bit of a pain)

For more information see

- [WinDbg 101–A step by step guide to finding a simple memory leak in your .Net application](http://alookonthecode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/windbg-101a-step-by-step-guide-to.html)
- [WinDbg / SOS Cheat Sheet](http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! That explains why I was so confused. I did read about sos.dll, but I incorrectly assumed that it merely had to be loaded for commands like htrace to work with CLR. I've gotten closer to a solution by using `!htrace` and then `!u` with the stack address. That seemed to also have problems walking across p-invoke frames, so I set a breakpoint at one of points returned by htrace, and used `!clrstack` to view the full CLR stack.